# Integrate Disqus in Hexo

Tags: node.js, disqus, hexo

I have a very basic but very annoyed question for me that I have a Hexo blog and want to integrate Disqus Comments capability. I'm using the [Beantech Hexo theme](https://github.com/YenYuHsuan/hexo-theme-beantech/) and it has a `disqus_username: kjanshair` property in `_config.yml` file. I tried the followings:

- Created a Disqus site and add the site name to `disqus_username` didn't work.
- Grab the custom integration code from disqus and tried to set it up in `footer.ejs` but didn't work.
- In the `page.ejs`, I also tried to uncomment the disqus code and provide correct values but still does not work

Anyone has any idea how resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide more details, or a repo with the issue could be easily reproduced.

Comment: What was the error message? more information is needed to solve this!!